# Whats is the standard way to build a html with values from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a html block in javascript

```
var html = `
            <div class='row'>
             <div class='form-group row'>
                <label for=nombre' class='col-2 col-form-label'>Nombre</label>
                <div class='col-4'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='text' value=`+empresa+` id='empresa' name='empresa'>
                </div>
            </div>`;
```

and use the jquery .html to write it into a div

```
$('#content').html(html);
```

This works fine and only when i want to use values i dont get the full "text".

the values on the server side (console.log) and on the client side (alert) are the same so the data is received ok.

i have the value in a variable after splitting

```
var response = data.q0;

var values = response.split(",");
var empresa = values[2];
```

and in my case the value is Alex Marcelo Aros Espinoza Ltda but in the input field i get only the word Alex.

how should i modify `value=`+empresa+

Comment: If you are using template literals, use string interpolation (\`${variable}\`), not concatentation

Comment: You haven't quoted the value you set to the `value` property. Try `value="\`+empresa+\`"` or, even better ``value="${empresa}"``

Comment: @titus thanks, both work fine. i will use value="${empresa}"

Answer (score -1):

Might try the following:

```
function makeRow(emp){
  var html = $("<div>", {
    class: "row"
  });
  $("<div>", {
    class: "form-group row"
  }).appendTo(html);
  $("<label>", {
    for: "nombre",
    class: "col-2 col-form-label"
  }).appendTo($(".form-group", html));
  $("<div>", {
    class: "col-4"
  }).appendTo($(".form-group", html));
  $("<input>", {
    class: "form-control",
    type: "text",
    value: emp,
    id: "empresa-" + ($("input[id^='empresa']").length + 1),
    name: "empresa"
  }).appendTo($(".col-4", html));
  return html;
}
```

Then in your AJAX:

```
var response = data.q0;

var values = response.split(",");
var empresa = values[2];

var row = makeRow(empresa);
$('#content').html(row);
```

Now, if you are making multiple rows, you may want to give them some unique IDs. Otherwise you will have multiple `id='empresa'` elements.

Hope that helps.